# Event in Tweepy Streaming

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

How does the event work in **tweepy streaming**?

Can anyone give an example?

I want to get unfollow or follow from Event, how do I do that?
I have tried before but I have not received any event

Answer (score 0):

You can't track unfollows using the Twitter API. The closest thing to that is getting all of a user's followers and polling it over time, but the won't work with a larger number of followers.

I suggest you familiarise yourself with Twitter's [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/introduction) so you can be more clear on what you *can* do with the Streaming API.

Comment: so how events work??
for example, how can i get follow from event?

Comment: You can't do that either, read the documentation I linked so you can familiarise yourself with what you're actually able to do.